# react-native-agora: Unsupported filename extension

Tags: react-native

error: node_modules/react-native-agora/src/specs/AgoraRtcSurfaceViewNativeComponent.tsx: /Users/mac/Documents/VideoCalling/node_modules/react-native-agora/src/specs/AgoraRtcSurfaceViewNativeComponent.tsx: Unable to parse file '/Users/mac/Documents/VideoCalling/node_modules/react-native-agora/src/specs/AgoraRtcSurfaceViewNativeComponent.tsx'. Unsupported filename extension.

MacOS: 14.3
React-native: 0.73.4
react-native-agora: 4.2.6

Answer (score 0):

rename AgoraRtcSurfaceViewNativeComponent.tsx to AgoraRtcSurfaceViewNativeComponent.ts

and
AgoraRtcTextureViewNativeComponent.tsx to AgoraRtcTextureViewNativeComponent.ts

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).